# Get specific word from text

Tags: text-processing

Inside `FILE.txt`

```
Interval: 5s
Interval: 3m
Interval: 1h
Interval: 7s
Interval: 5m
Interval: 3h
```

What I want to do:

1. Print only the word that has s (so the output will be 5s and 7s)
2. Print only the word that has s or m or h

How to do this?

Comment: can u plz share the difficulty your facing ...

Comment: @msp9011? I'm new to this

Comment: What have you done on your own, where are you stuck? This site already has loads of similar questions, just look around (use the search).

Comment: Is the input always exactly in the format shown in the question, i.e. you always want the 2nd word if it matches?

Comment: @Panki yes, I'm stuck at head -n 1 FILE.txt | grep -o "*s"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

Print only the word that has s

```
echo $TEXT | grep -o '[0-9]*s'
5s
7s
```

Print only the word that has s or m or h

```
echo $TEXT | grep -o '[0-9]*[smh]'
5s
3m
1h
7s
5m
3h
```

> From man:

- `grep -o` Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.

**For your updated question:**

- To print the last field if it has `s`

  ```
  awk '$NF~/s/{print $NF}' FILE.txt
  5s
  7s
  ```
- To print the last field if it has `s` or `h` or `m`

  ```
   awk '$NF~/s/ || $NF~/m/ || $NF~/h/ {print $NF}' FILE.txt
   5s
   3m
   1h
   7s
   5m
   3h
  ```

Comment: Thx that's work @msp9011, sorry for late reply